# Camelot tables extraction- Concatenate multiple tables into one excel

Tags: python, pdf, python-camelot

I have a a pdf with multiple tables. I managed to extract them using camelot, but my question is how can I concatenate all the tables in one excel file?
I tried concat function :

```
        tables = camelot.read_pdf('foo.pdf', pages= "all")
        if tables:
            df = pd.concat(tables, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel('foo.xlsx')
```

But I get this error message : cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'camelot.core.Table'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Answer (score 0):

The camelot tables are not, as suggests the error, pandas objects (Series, DataFrame). Try to convert them to dataframes or to CSV and then to `pd.DataFrame` (again a pandas dataframe).
To convert a camelot table to a dataframe you can do:

```
table_df = table.df
```

[camelot-py: PDF Table Extraction](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/)